How scipy deals with minimization with equality constraints?
I would like to ask if someone could briefly explain to me how python packages such as SciPy, and specifically scipy.optimize.minimize(..., method='SLSQP') deal with constraints hj(x) = 0. What is the mathematics behind the codes?
Assume that one wants to minimize a function

subject to both equality constraints (gi(x) <= 0, i = 1, 2, ..., N) and inequality constraints (hj(x) = 0, j = 1, 2, ..., M.) I would like to ask if someone could briefly explain how python packages such as SciPy deal with constraints.
I understand that one can turn an equality constraint into an inequality constraint, by re-writing hj(x) = 0 into -ε <= hj(x) <= ε. But when I code this, it seems the convergence is extremely slow.

While you cannot write in LaTeX on Stackoverflow, you should not post your question as an image. Please write your question as text (and don't surround LaTeX terms with $ since that makes it more difficult to read). Just express things in words. "Assume that one wants to minimize a function f(x) for x in some domain... h_j(x) = 0 for j = 1, 2, ..., M..." Also, you mention some code that doesn't work well. Share your code.

THANKS jared! I did not have the code. I just wanted to see the theory behind the codes.

"But when I code this, it seems the convergence is extremely slow." It sounds like you do have code. Also, you didn't address my comment about rewriting your post so it isn't an image.

This is an ambiguous question, because SciPy has multiple ways of solving such a problem. For example, if your constraints are linear, then scipy.optimize.linprog() can be used. If the constraints are nonlinear, then scipy.optimize.minimize() could be used. Even within scipy.optimize.minimize(), SciPy supports three algorithms that can use equality constraints: trust-constr, SLSQP, and COBYQA. I have not checked, but I would bet that all of these use differing approaches to solve this problem. Can you edit the question to clarify which part of SciPy you're asking about?

Thanks Nick! I have edited it. It is mostly about scipy.optimize.minimize()

Of the three minimize algorithms i mentioned, is there one you're interested in?

Nick: thank you! I would love to know all of them but if it is limited, can I ask about  SLSQP?

See:

Kraft D (1988), A software package for sequential quadratic
programming. Tech. Rep. DFVLR-FB 88-28, DLR German Aerospace Center —
Institute for Flight Mechanics, Koln, Germany.


This paper can be found online here.

Thanks Erwin and Nick! I will read the paper.
